# Clone the contents of h1 tag and display them as background

Tags: javascript, jquery, background

I was trying to clone the contents of `h1` tag and display them as background in a div.

Can it be done?

What I tried:

```
<script>
    $( "h1" ).clone().prependTo( ".h1Back" );
</script>

<div class="h1Back">

</div>
```

but if it worked I guess it would be in the foreground.

Comment: That would be equally or more about the CSS than js or HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can not put text "in the background of a div", but you can use z-index to put a div in the background of another div, this is how it works in a simplified example:

```
<div id="back" style="z-index: 1;"></div>
<div id="fore" style="z-index: 2;">Whatever you want in the foreground</div>
```

And the jQuery part:

```
$('#back').html( $('h1').html() );
```

Getting the html from h1 and putting it as content to the background div.

Comment: thanks for the help. that kind of worked but that seems to remove everything else. i also tryed :

Comment: arrgh. much of the same. how would i go about cloning it?